# Using City to find county in google sheets

Tags: excel

I have two spreadsheets. One with all cities and what county each city corresponds too in California. The second spreadsheet has people information, and what city they are from. This information was provided with a google form.

I want to use the first spreadsheet to auto populate a column in the second spreadsheet and show what county each person is from based on the city. Is there some sort of script or vlookup that can do this?  I have included the screenshots of each excel file here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVE0J.png)

Answer (score 0):

Insert a column into the second spreadsheet and a VLOOKUP should work, assuming the city values in the first and second spreadsheets line up. I'd run a TRIM() function on both columns to eliminate any trailing spaces if the VLOOKUP returns a bunch of errors.

Comment: what do you mean by "first and second spread sheets line up"? I've never really used Vlookup before. The cities in both spreadsheets just go in random order.

Comment: Ah gotcha, I should've been a bit more explicit. The values not lining up in terms of their order within the spreadsheets makes it a perfect application for VLOOKUP. What you may need to watch out for is the possibility of error output due to a cell value not being present in both spreadsheets. This error output can be caused by a leading/trailing space in the cell (i.e. 'Los Angeles' <> 'Los Angeles '). Running a TRIM() function will ensure that any error outputs generated are not caused by spaces.